# Sample Extjs5 App for Unit testing with Jasmine and Karma-runner

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, extjs5

I'am new to Extjs5 and trying to run jasmine unit test cases with karma-runner. Although am sucessfully able to do that fro Ext4.2 application but same process is not working for Extjs5.

I have goggled it but didn't got any useful link

If anyone have already executed for Ext5 app please share the code.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Tapaswini

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to allow the required ExtJS classes to properly load *before* you start your test. 
Make sure you include the following in your karma.conf.js

```
// We need to add an element with the ID 'appLoadingIndicator' because [app.js].launch() is     expecting it and tries to remove it

// Karma normally starts the tests right after all files specified in 'karma.config.js' have been loaded
// We only want the tests to start after Sencha Touch/ExtJS has bootstrapped the application
// 1. We temporary override the '__karma__.loaded' function
// 2. When Ext is ready we call the '__karma__.loaded' function manually
var karmaLoadedFunction = window.__karma__.loaded;
window.__karma__.loaded = function () {
};

bootstrapExtJS(); // Create this function to add anything that is not included in your class definition requires and you need to require explicitly

Ext.onReady(function () {
  window.__karma__.loaded = karmaLoadedFunction;
  window.__karma__.loaded();
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.